# Javafx vs Swing para la distribucion de aplicaciones

Tags: java-swing, javafx, modulos, maven-compiler-plugin, inicializacion

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en Java que necesito distribuir de forma fácil a varias empresas. Para el diseño de la aplicación decidí utilizar JavaFx. Sin embargo me he encontrado con grandes problemas a la hora de ejecutar la aplicación en otros sistemas operativos. Investigando eh encontrado información sobre herramientas como jlink y packager, pero estas generan ejecutables solo para el sistema en que se utiliza (si se hace en Windows, solo corre en Windows) y Java da la posibilidad de codificar y tener la seguridad de que correrá en todos los OS. Así que mi pregunta es: Hay alguna forma de crear un distribuible de JavaFx que pueda ser ejecutado en todos lo sistemas? Existe alguna herramienta q facilite la creación del mismo? Si alguien usa JavaFx para programar y distribuir sus apps, podría decirme como le hace?

Comment: Hola Victor, tu pregunta es demasiado amplia, y para más INRI, es en parte, basada en opiniones, te recomiendo que la edites, enfocandote en un tema, y si es necesario, formular varias preguntas distintas (siempre sin pedir opiniones), de esa manera, te evitarás recibir votos negativos, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida y obtengas una mejor respuesta, y de paso, aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Comment: La idea es *"Codifica una vez, ejecuta donde sea"* -que haya una JVM compatible- se mantiene aunque tengas que hacer 3 o 4 empaquetados diferentes, ya que el bytecode es el mismo. Evalúa si te sirve [Java Web Start](https://www.java.com/es/download/help/java_webstart_es.html) o [las herramientas propias de JFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/deployment_toolkit.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Problema resuelto con maven-assebly-plugin (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html) aquí hay información sobre como utilizarlo -> https://github.com/SvS30/JavaFX-Maven, si busca el archivo POM.xml tendrá una referencia de uso, dejo la configuración del POM.xml con algunos comentarios para referencias, muchas gracias:

```
<!-- Para trabajar se deben adicionar las dependecias del programa, q seran las librerias usadas>
<!-- Estas dependecias seran las mismas que usara en SceneBuilder de ser necesario>
<!-- Por ejemplo, aqui se usa: <artifactId>controlsfx</artifactId> >
<!-- Las dependecias utilizadas seran descargadas por maven y puestas en la carpeta .m2 en forma de jar>
<!-- Se utilizara la misma ruta que en el RepositorioCentral de maven>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
        <version>19</version>
    </dependency>
<!-- En esta dependecia se ha configurado los graficos para linux>
<!-- En caso de querer correr la plicacion en windows usar: <classifier>win</classifier> >
    <!-- En caso de querer correr la plicacion en mac usar: <classifier>mac</classifier> >
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
        <version>19</version>
        <classifier>linux</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.jensd</groupId>
        <artifactId>fontawesomefx</artifactId>
        <version>8.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.controlsfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>controlsfx</artifactId>
        <version>11.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
    <!-- Se elige la version de java q utilizas en este caso 19>
    <!-- Se elige la version de java objetivo, en este caso la 19>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>19</source>
                <target>19</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <!-- Default configuration for running with: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                    <id>default-cli</id>
                    <configuration>
            <!-- Aqui se dice la ruta de la clase main>
                        <!-- Ten en cuenta que la clase main debe ser otra aparte de la que extiende de Application>
                        <mainClass>com.example.demo9/com.example.demo9.Launcher</mainClass>
                        <launcher>app</launcher>
                        <jlinkZipName>app</jlinkZipName>
                        <jlinkImageName>app</jlinkImageName>
                        <noManPages>true</noManPages>
                        <stripDebug>true</stripDebug>
                        <noHeaderFiles>true</noHeaderFiles>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-jar</id>
                    <phase>none</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.2</version>
            <configuration>
        <!-- El nombre del .jar resultante>
                <finalName>javafx-sample</finalName>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
            <!-- Otra vez la ruta de la clase main>
                        <mainClass>com.example.demo9.Launcher</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                    <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```